# Converting ul li list to Select dropdown

Tags: select, html-lists, html-select

I have the following structure HTML code

```
<ul id="list_abcxyz">
        <li class="label even-row">
                    <a class="label-link lia-link-navigation" rel="tag" id="link_c19bf51ba9103c" href="test.html">Label One<wbr></a>
                        <span class="label-count">(1)</span>
        </li>

        <li class="label odd-row">  
                    <a class="label-link lia-link-navigation" rel="tag" id="link_c19bf51ba9103c_0" href="test2.html">Label Two<wbr></a>
                    <span class="label-count">(1)</span>
        </li>
        <li class="label even-row">
                    <a class="label-link lia-link-navigation" rel="tag" id="link_c19bf51ba9103c_1" href="test3.html">Label Three<wbr></a>
                        <span class="label-count">(1)</span>
        </li>
```

How to convert it to a select drop down? I have tried following the guides in community. But those didn't work. I guess because of extra span tag. But I need that span tag as well.

How can we convert it to select option drop down using JS ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started. If you were running into trouble with the `<span>` then you can use the `textContent` property to get all text without the html tags included, then remove all multiple spaces with a replace() and trim().

```js
var myform = document.getElementById('myform'),
    items = document.getElementById('list_abcxyz').getElementsByTagName('li'),
    select = document.createElement('select'),
    len = items.length,
    option;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  option = document.createElement('option');
  var label = items[i].textContent.replace(/\s\s+/g," ").trim(),
      link = items[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
  
  option.textContent = label;
  option.value = link;
  
  select.appendChild(option);
  
}

myform.appendChild(select);

select.addEventListener('change',function(evt){
  var selectedLink = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(selectedLink);
  
  location.href = selectedLink;
});
```

```html
<ul id="list_abcxyz">
        <li class="label even-row">
                    <a class="label-link lia-link-navigation" rel="tag" id="link_c19bf51ba9103c" href="test.html">Label One<wbr></a>
                        <span class="label-count">(1)</span>
        </li>

        <li class="label odd-row">  
                    <a class="label-link lia-link-navigation" rel="tag" id="link_c19bf51ba9103c_0" href="test2.html">Label Two<wbr></a>
                    <span class="label-count">(1)</span>
        </li>
        <li class="label even-row">
                    <a class="label-link lia-link-navigation" rel="tag" id="link_c19bf51ba9103c_1" href="test3.html">Label Three<wbr></a>
                        <span class="label-count">(1)</span>
        </li>
</ul>

<form id="myform">
  
</form>
```

Comment: Also, note that currently the value of the option is set to the "Label One (1)" If you wanted to set it to just "Label One" you could just do another replace() to remove the (1).

Comment: Thank you. That works. What should I do to load selected page(href source) from the drop down?